# Azure App Configuration not loading the keys

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-app-configuration

I am trying to load some key/value pairs defined in my Azure App Configuration service inside my DotNet 6.0 web application. But it returns nothing [ **the call to builder.Configuration.GetSection("Rental:Settings")**].Any Idea?

Here is the code I am using:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, config) =>
{
    var settings = config.Build();
    if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(c=>
        {
            c.Connect(ConnectionString); // Copied from Access key section 
        });
    }   
});
```

Load it into a class:

```
builder.Services.Configure<AppSetings>(**builder.Configuration.GetSection("Rental:Settings")**);
```

Key/Value

[image]

Comment: `var settings = config.Build();` must be called after all configuration is done.

Comment: Just did it. Still not working.

Comment: Refer this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226083/dynamically-reading-azure-app-configuration-in-net-core-web-app-using-net-6), check if you added middleware.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same issue as https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/105624. By default, the library loads key-values with "no label", but key-values you created have labels. Use the `Select` API to specify the label you want to load.

```cs
config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.Connect(connectionString)
           .Select("*", "replace with your label");
});
```

Comment: Hi, I figured this out yesterday. Thanks for the comment.